# Use string variable to set object variable in VBA? (Excel 2013)

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a number of ActiveX controls/buttons on a page, and I would like to modify several of the parameters of the buttons (in a loop function).

I am fine with writing the loop function to achieve this, but cannot find a way to refer to the object using a string variable.  I have set up an object variable (as per below), and a string variable to be used to change the reference for the object variable - but can't find a way to get it to work.

This is the code that does *NOT* work:

```
Private Sub TrialCode_Click()

Dim ButtonObj As Object
Dim ButtonCaption As String
Dim ButtonString As String

ButtonString = "CommandButton1"
Set ButtonObj = ButtonString

ButtonCaption = "Something"

ButtonObj.Caption = ButtonCaption  'example of the kind of parameters I want to change

End Sub
```

The `Set ButtonObj = ButtonString` is the command that fails, reporting a *Type Mismatch* error.

I'm working in Excel 2013.

I really hope there is some way to do this.  Any help will be really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CommandButton belongs to an `OLEObject`

try

```
ButtonString = "CommandButton1"
Set ButtonObj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(ButtonString)

ButtonCaption = "Something"
ButtonObj.Object.Caption = ButtonCaption  'example of the kind of parameters I want to change
```

Note that some properties occur directly under `ButtonObj`, others such as *Caption* sit below *Object*

[image]

Comment: Using the Locals window to see the hierarchy of the properties is an excellent point.